# Splitting a string with regex whitespace delimitor

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split

I have a string with this delimitor ' - ' (hyphen surrounded by spaces).
I have no problem getting each part of the string:

```
select regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 1),
       regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 2)
from (select 'first - second' as val from dual) t
```

However I would like to exclude spaces between each term and the hyphen. I tried this:

```
regexp_substr(val, '[^\s-]+', 1, 1)
regexp_substr(val, '[^-\s]+', 1, 2)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. THe first expression returns `fir`,

1) I wonder why?
Here is the link to Fiddle:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/41570

2) How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split your string so you don't need *Negated Character Classes*,you can split with following pattern:

```
'[\s-]+'
```

And if you just want to find the words you can use :

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+\b
```

Comment: Thank you Kasra but I can't retrieve a correct outcome using your regexp. How would you  use them in my case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove spaces from the beginning and end, then I think the simplest approach is to use `trim()`:

```
select trim(regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 1)),
       trim(regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 2))
from (select 'first - second' as val from dual) t
```

Comment: Thank you, the trim funciton does the trick so I am using it! However what would be a possible regexp to solve th eproblem without trimming?

Answer (score 0):

Capture your target in a group and have the function return that:

```
select regexp_substr(val, '(.*) *- *', 1, 1, '', 1),
   regexp_substr(val, ' *- *(.*)', 1, 1, '', 1)
from (select 'first - second' as val from dual) t
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/3795)

This allows you to express more precisely your delimiter. This technique is the next best thing to using a look ahead expression, which would be the approach most favoured in regex engines that support it and which Oracle does not support.

To explain what's going on, the target is *captured* using brackets and it returned using a back reference - the last parameter - naming group 1 (the *first* group of the expression) to be returned.

FYI group 0 is the *whole* match.